# Extracting properties using SimpleCommandLinePropertySource does not work in Java

Tags: java, spring, args

Trying to extract command line arguments using  SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(arg)

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource argument = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(arg);
}
```

When i print argument, this is printed:

```
SimpleCommandLinePropertySource {name='commandLineArgs'}
```

This is how i call the main class from eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing `s` in parameter `arg(s)`? Maybe you have some additional `arg` defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc for `SimpleCommandLinePropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.html) states

> ### Working with option arguments
>
> Option arguments must adhere to the exact syntax:
>
> ```
> --optName[=optValue]
> ```
>
> That is, options must be prefixed with "--" and may or may not specify a value. If a value is specified, the name and value must be separated without spaces by an equals sign ("="). The value may optionally be an empty string.

You're providing your property argument as

```
 -key=value
```

which is not the syntax `SimpleCommandLinePropertySource` is expecting and it therefore ignores it.

Provide the argument in the format specified, then you can retrieve the parsed properties normally, ie. through [`getProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-).